# Search file contents of a json file in PHP and return results

Tags: php, json, search

I am trying to create a search a function in php which searches for the data contained inside a Json file. I am able to do this for a normal text file which returns a list of results based on what has been entered in the search field which returns closet match. However does not work when doing this same for a json file and does not return anything.

**search.php**

```
if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['txt'])) {

    $search = $_POST['txt'];
    $file = file('data/contacts.json');
    $found = false;

    $jsonData = json_decode($file, true);

    foreach ($jsonData as $line) {
        if (strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
            $found = true;
            echo $line;
        }
    }
    if (!$found) {
        echo 'No match found';
    }
}
```

contacts.json

```
[
    {
    "id": 3,
    "forename": "John",
    "surname": "Smith",
    "email": "j@hotmail.com",
    "address": "addresss",
    "telephone": "01232302323"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "forename": "Keith",
    "surname": "Miller",
    "email": "K@hotmail.com",
    "address": "ssdsds",
    "telephone": "01232302323"
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "forename": "Doug",
    "surname": "Howard",
    "email": "d@hotmail.com",
    "address": "test",
    "telephone": "01232302323"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "forename": "r",
    "surname": "r",
    "email": "email@gmail.com",
    "address": "test",
    "telephone": "01232302323"
}

 ]
```

Comment: `JSON` is not plain text when you decode it , it becomes an `array` or `object` or whatever.. if you want just to read it as plain text use `file_get_contents` without decoding it , but then again the json could be one line, instead of containing tabs, spaces

Comment: Can we see the json ?

Comment: I have now included the json file in the question

Comment: I have used file_get_contents and it now returns the following - ArrayArrayArrayArray

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `$jsonData = json_decode($file, true);` to

`$jsonData = json_decode(json_encode($file),true);`