# Search in JSON file and show value from field next to it

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm searching in this JSON file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sector3studios/r3e-spectator-overlay/master/r3e-data.json

```
$search = '2054';
$file = file('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sector3studios/r3e-spectator-overlay/master/r3e-data.json');
$found = false;

$jsonData = json_decode(json_encode($file),true);

foreach ($jsonData as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
        $found = true;
        echo $line;
        echo $jsonData['Class'];
    }
}
if (!$found) {
    echo 'No match found';
}
```

I can now find `"Id": 2054,`

But I need the `"Class": 1685,` that comes with it.

Can someone help me to get that? Sorry i'm new to JSON and array searching & echoing. I have tried to find some solutions but it doesn't work. I think it's because of the complex way the array has been made. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's this : `json_decode(json_encode($file),true);` ?

Comment: Can you please add a language tag to your post so people can immediately see which language the solution is supposed to be written in :)

Comment: @Cid, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53131894/1510309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you take a very nice json and you use it as a string to make your search. The most efficient and precise way is to loop the json object and find the items you want.

So first of all, instead of opening the file line-by-line, load it all together, using `file_get_contents` instead of `file`

```
$file = file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sector3studios/r3e-spectator-overlay/master/r3e-data.json');
```

Then, instead of encoding/decoding, just decode it once so it's transformed in an object like this

```
$jsonData = json_decode($file);
```

Loop the resulting object with

```
foreach ($jsonData->cars as $car_id => $data) {
    foreach ($data->liveries as $liverie) {
```

This is a nested foreach since the source json has a 2-level nesting and your "Id" is find within the `liveries` objects.

Now within the last `foreach` you can use your search term to match the `Id`

```
if ($liverie->Id == $search) {
```

And you can access the Class you needed with

```
$liverie->Class;
```

Here's the overall code:

```
$search = '2054';
$file = file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sector3studios/r3e-spectator-overlay/master/r3e-data.json');
$found = false;

$jsonData = json_decode($file);
foreach ($jsonData->cars as $car_id => $data) {
    foreach ($data->liveries as $liverie) {
        if ($liverie->Id == $search) {
            $found = true;
            echo $liverie->Id.PHP_EOL;
            echo $liverie->Class.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a hero! Now I also understand what was wrong, it's because of the 2nd level nesting. I also tried the foreach before but because of the 2nd level it wasn't responding. Thanks again hero.